# Multiple env files choosing which one on docker - create react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

I am building a react app using cra, so the problem is the application just has the client side code which means there is no nodejs part.

I have two different environments one is development and one is production, as cra tells there is a order of preference:

```
.env
.env.development
.env.production
```

So if .env.production file is there in repo it will take that one and use that config based on the script that I give, if I use npm run build it will use .env.production and if I use npm start it will use .env.development if the file is there.

So I can add .env, .env.development, .env.production, but when I build the image in the Docker I can give only one command either it should be `npm start` or `npm run build`. So how should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Install a local development environment; typically your only host dependency will be Node itself.  Use the `.env.development` file there, via something like the Webpack dev server, with a command like `yarn start`.

Use Docker principally as a deployment mechanism.  Your Dockerfile can build your application using the `.env.production` file, and then copy it into something like an Nginx container that doesn't need Node at all.  It should follow the pattern in the CRA [Creating a Production Build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build) docs.  Loosely,

```sh
FROM node:lts AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package.lock .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# Base image provides default EXPOSE, CMD
```

This pattern gets around all of the difficulties of trying to make Docker act like a local development environment (filesystem permissions, `node_modules` not updating, live reloading being flaky, ...) by just using an actual local development environment; but at deployment time you get the benefits of a self-contained Docker image with no host dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the response ,yeah i am using ngnix but the problem is as you have one line of npm run build obviously it will pick the .env.production for prod env it will be fine but for another env like development how it will take the .env.development because i will be using the same Docker file for dev environment also ?

Comment: Use `node` on your host for a dev environment.  It is easier to install than Docker, and every IDE comes preconfigured to use it with no special setup.

Comment: But i am not using node, is there any way to do with docker ngnix and create react app, i am trying in that way without node. I know you can change the env with use of bash script adding a file i have tried that also, but is there any way rather than this ?

Comment: @ David, thanks for the help, but are you able to understand what i am trying for ?

Comment: Currently it seems there is no other way to pass multiple environment file based on development and production environment.